# INNER JOIN stop query from working

Tags: php, mysql, join

I must be doing something wrong, i have this query, however when i add the inner join it stop working, any help or advice much appreciated.  All field names have been triple checked and are correct.  When i remove the inner join the product name echos perfectly.

```
    $result_c = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM products INNER JOIN images on products.product_code=images.product_code WHERE products.new='1'");
$row_product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_c); ?>

<?php echo $row_product['product_name']; ?>
```

Comment: Inner join will ensure that data is present across tables and additional condition if provided, you may need to provide some sample data from both tables.

Comment: It looks like your joining values aren't referenced. Try a left join.

Comment: table structure is : (products) product_id, product_code, product_name, product_desc, price, color, new, clearance.      (images)  product_code, product_image_big1.     and to display <?php echo $row_product['product_name']; ?>

Comment: Your stated product has no images.

Comment: that was it, thanks.  i'm such a tool sometimes, working on new template forgot to alter img url.  thanks  how do i accept answer of comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables.

If your query stopped working after adding an INNER JOIN, it means there is no match between the tables. Table b has no values for table q or vica versa.

Try to make sure there are values in there.